# Git strategy to minimize merge conflicts over multiple repos

Tags: git

An external software vendor delivers *product updates* as complete snapshots as a zip file. In this case it is `external-base.zip`. Furthermore, it also delivers other zip files that are almost identical, but are localized versions of the software.

**Problem**

The problem is that I need to keep some modifications to this software, while simultaneously minimize manual merge conflict resolution.

1. To do so, I first create git repositories `ext-base`, `extLC_EN`,
   `extLC_GE` and commit to them each time I recieve a new zip file.
2. Next, I push whatever is inside `extBase` into `intBase`. When I
   create modifications, I add them to `intBase`. Each time I push from
   `extBase` into `intBase`, I might risk losing my modifications.
3. As I want my modifications also to end up in the localized versions,
   I push from `intBase` into `intLC_EN` and `intLC_GE`.

*=> So I have to resolve conflicts on `intBase`, `intLC_EN`, and `intLC_GE` each time when those 3 newly updated zip files arrive, all the while the resolutions of these conflicts would be similar.*

**Considerations**

1. Base and LC-versions have almost the same structure.
2. Would [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) be of any help here?

**Question**

What strategy could you recommend me to minimize work?

[image: Depiction of repositories]

Comment: Sending zip files around sounds like a poor approach to version control. If their code is version controlled, can't they send you a git bundle or something? Then you can do branch merges, etc.

Comment: @CoryKramer agreed, but assume a really stupid software vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What strategy could you recommend me to minimize work?

Import your vendor snapshots to a single history dag, with a branch structure chosen by you (since the vendor's not supplying ancestry you have a free hand, it's entirely for your convenience). Then maintain your own work as branches on those.

> Would `git rerere` be of any help here?

`git rerere` was *made* for this, for easing the task of applying a set of changes when merging histories from … wherever.

---

For a concrete example of the vendor history you want to construct, let's use this:

```
  a---b---c-------e    LC_EN  (let's say you somehow didn't import the fourth one)
 /   /   /       /
A---B---C---D---E      external-base perhaps aka master
 \   \   \   \   \
  α---β---γ---δ---ε    LC_GE
```

with `A`, `B`, `C` etc. snapshots tagged with their vendor revision numbers. Git famously just doesn't care *how* you do your work, the point is to do it.

That looks about right for the setup you've described.  Your changes are a parallel branch structure, with `A'` being your changes on the external `A` base, `α'` being your `A'` work applied onto the `α` base, and so on.  (Sorry for using greek instead of the Georgian alphabet, it's what I know).

Let's say you're up to `D`in your existing repositories, and you've got the `E` set of `.zip`s.

---

Job One is to construct the vendor base history.  Job Two is to construct your patched history. Job Three is to get the new-vendor-release dance down cold.

The thing to understand is that Git finds a repo, and its work tree, index and object db, if you don't tell it explicitly, but you can just tell it.  Say you've got an extracted vendor download that looks exactly like a content snapshot (because it is one), so tell Git that's the work tree you're adding from.

Here's a pretty direct way. Let's start with your existing constructed histories, let's say you're up to `D` so far and you recorded no `d` snapshot, hey, it happens.

---

edit: I'm happy to flesh out the remainder of this but (a) I've got things to do today and the git core commands are offputting to some, and (b) just the details of the mind-that-first step might be enough to set you on the right path.  Ask about any confusing or simply not-clear-enough details and I'll put more work into it.

---

Job one: construct the desired vendor base history from the snapshots in your existing repositories.  To keep things simple-ish while still providing a little tour of Git's git-r-dun flavor, let's construct a new unified vendor history repo.

```
git init /path/to/new-vendor-history      # make the unified-vendor-history repo
cd !$                                     # switch to it
mkdir -p .git/objects/info                # set it up to leech off the older histories
printf %s\\n >.git/objects/info/alternates \
   /path/to/old/{extBase,extLC-EN,extLC_GE}/.git/objects
```

This is quicker and cheaper than adding remotes for all the existing repos and fetching their histories, you'll be weaning yourself off the old-history teat soon enough but for now, just tell Git hey, there's a bunch of objects in these places I'm using for now.

Since you're taking your extBase repo's history verbatim, just take it. You've already told git where to find the objects, the quickest way to point your current branch (the as-yet-unspecified local `master`) at that history is

```
git reset -q $(git -C /path/to/old/extBase rev-parse master)  \
                                          # set my master branch to current extBase tip
```

and now, since for this example you're up to `D` in your existing repos, your `new-vendor-history` `master` looks like

```
A---B---C---D
```

because that's what you just reset it to.

So to finish the first job, it's time to construct your vendor localization branches from the existing snapshots. Start the branch off with the existing snapshot and a single parent (I'm using the letters from the commit graph I drew above, sub in the actual hash id's or any other ref git can resolve to those here)

```
git branch LC_EN A
```

then to add a merge of the `b` tree

```
git update-ref refs/heads/LC_EN $(
        git commit-tree -p LC_EN -p B -m 'your merge message here' b:
        )
```

and so on for each.  `b` here is the existing corresponding commit in your `extLC_EN` repo, the resulting commit, the resulting commit in your `new-vendor-base` repo is the one I drew as `b` above.

Do that again for the `LC_GE` branch and you're done restructuring your already-gitted vendor snapshots. Now you can repack and cut ties:

```
git repack -ad
rm .git/objects/info/alternates
```

The only thing left to do to finish converting the vendor snapshots to the new system is to add new snapshots from the downloaded `E` set of `.zip`s.

```
( cd ~/down; unzip external-base.zip )        # unpack the new snapshot
git --work-tree ~/down/external-base add .    # add to repo and update index from there
git commit                                    # commit to the current tip

( cd ~/down; unzip external-LC_EN.zip )       # unpack the new snapshot
git --work-tree ~/down/external-LC_EN add .   # add to repo and update index from there
git update-ref refs/heads/LC_EN $(            # commit to a different tip
        git commit-tree -p LC_EN -p master -m 'vendor LC_EN' `git write-tree`
        )

( cd ~/down; unzip external-LC_GE.zip )       # unpack the new snapshot
git --work-tree ~/down/external-LC_GE add .   # add to repo and update index from there
git update-ref refs/heads/LC_GE $(            # commit to a different tip
        git commit-tree -p LC_GE -p master -m 'vendor LC_GE' `git write-tree`
        )
```

(you probably want to write a little script to factor out the boilerplate and sub the vendor versions into the commit messages, maybe even a repo-local git alias if you're willing to step that carefully through the three-layers-of-quoting minefield, *especially* since this is the first step in your new-vendor-release dance).

---

So that's Job One, the heavy lifting, the going-back-and-converting-your-existing-structure-to-a-single-unified-vendor-history work.

---

Job Two is bringing your patches up to speed with the new system as well.

You could, if you wanted, carry your patches in that same repository.  I'd do it that way, I make separate repos only when (a) I have some concrete use for multiple independent, concurrent work trees or (b) I've got that uh-oh-here's-my-chance-to-really-screw-up-the-refs-namespace feeling and I want a clone I can just abandon if things go south.  But here you're going to have

So let's accumulate your `rerere` catalog by way of showing how to import existing `intXYZ` histories in similar fashion.

```
git config rerere.enabled true                # light auto-rerere
printf %s\\n >.git/objects/info/alternates \
    /path/to/old/int{Base,LC_EN,LC_GE}/.git/objects
```

Now: rerere works by noticing any new conflicts or resolutions and resolving any old ones in the work tree and index it's run in.  Lighting auto-rerere just means `git rerere` runs whenever a merge stops with a conflict and whenever you commit the correct results of a conflicted merge, you can run it yourself whenever that's useful.